# awk + can't cut the field from iostat

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, iostat

when I do the follwing , then we get output

```
iostat -x 1|grep sdb
sdb               0.00    13.65    4.17   11.65   113.72   991.55   139.74     0.24   15.39    3.27   19.73   0.46   0.72
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

now I want to cut the second field , but now we not get output

```
[root@linux1 ~]#   iostat -x 1|grep sdb | awk '{print $2}'
```

also that , no output from pipe ,

```
iostat -x 1|grep sdb | more
```

why?

Comment: `iostat -x 1 | awk '/sdb/{print $2}'` or a more specific ``iostat -x 1 | awk '$1 == "sdb"{print $2}'`` will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
iostat -x 1 | grep --line-buffered "sdb" | awk '{print $2}'
```

OR with only `awk`:

```
iostat -x 1 | awk '/sdb/{print $2;fflush();}'
```

***OR***

```
iostat -x 1 | awk '$1=="sdb"{print $2;fflush();}'
```

***From `man awk` page:***

> fflush([file])        Flush any buffers associated with the open
>   output file or pipe file. If file is missing or if it is the null
>   string, then  flush  all open output files and pipes.